# Spring JPA @Procedure not working correctly with multiple OUT clause

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

Not able to map or get the desired results using Spring JPA for below setup.
My Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name] AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE Products AS TARGET
USING UpdatedProducts AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID) 
--When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.ProductName <> SOURCE.ProductName OR TARGET.Rate <> SOURCE.Rate 
THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.ProductName = SOURCE.ProductName, TARGET.Rate = SOURCE.Rate 
--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) VALUES (SOURCE.ProductID, SOURCE.ProductName, SOURCE.Rate)
--When there is a row that exists in target and same record does not exist in source then delete this record target
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
THEN DELETE 
--$action specifies a column of type nvarchar(10) in the OUTPUT clause that returns 
--one of three values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE' according to the action that was performed on that row
OUTPUT 
DELETED.ProductID AS TargetProductID, 
INSERTED.ProductID AS SourceProductID
END;
GO
```

My @Repository class looks like:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "sp_name")
Map<String, Integer> callingSP();
```

Getting below Exception:

> Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null

Please help on what went wrong?

Comment: Cross posted as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2161

Comment: Your repo definition doesn't look correct. Both `TargetProductID` and `SourceProductID` are `Nullable<int>` here, which in Java would be `Integer`, because one can be null for insert operations and the other null for delete operations.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Even if i use Map<String,Object> it doesn't work. have raised a bug in github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2161 for the same.

Comment: Seems like you should be using something like `@Entity public class UpdatedProducts { @Column private Integer TargetProductID; @Column private Integer SourceProductID; }` along with `@Procedure(name = "sp_name") List<UpdatedProducts> callingSP();`. But I'm not a keen JPA user.

Comment: Tried that as well @AlwaysLearning... But same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For result sets that don't exist as a table already (and hence have an `@Entity`-decorated class definition somewhere) the trick seems to be using an `interface` for the results of `@Query`-decorated methods that are declared in your repositories.

Given the SQL setup for your stored procedure...

```sql
use master;
go
create database StackOverflow;
go
use StackOverflow;
go
create table dbo.Products(
    ProductID int not null,
    ProductName nvarchar(50),
    Rate float
);
go
create table dbo.UpdatedProducts(
    ProductID int not null,
    ProductName nvarchar(50),
    Rate float
);
go
insert dbo.Products (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) values
    (10, 'Ten', 10.10),
    (20, 'Twenty', 20.20);
insert dbo.UpdatedProducts (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) values
    (20, 'Twenty', 20),
    (30, 'Thirty', 30);
go
select * from dbo.Products;
select * from dbo.UpdatedProducts;
go
```

Which yields...

| ProductID | ProductName | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Ten | 10.1 |
| 20 | Twenty | 20.199999999999999 |

| ProductID | ProductName | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Twenty | 20.0 |
| 30 | Thirty | 30.0 |

Then, in Java we have...

```java
// MergeResult.java
public interface MergeResult {
  Integer getSourceProductID();
  Integer getTargetProductID();
}
```

```java
// ProductsRepository.java
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "EXEC dbo.sp_name")
    List<MergeResult> callingSP();
}
```

```java
// FooJpaApplication.java
import java.util.List;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FooJpaApplication {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooJpaApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FooJpaApplication.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo(ProductsRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
      log.info("Executing sp_name()");
      log.info("-------------------");
      List<MergeResult> results = repository.callingSP();
      for (MergeResult r : results) {
        String line = String.format("TargetProductID=%d; SourceProductID=%d", r.getTargetProductID(),
            r.getSourceProductID());
        log.info(line);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Which yields the log output...

```
...
2021-02-25 20:30:01.136  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : Started FooJpaApplication in 3.076 seconds (JVM running for 3.388)
2021-02-25 20:30:01.138  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : Executing sp_name()
2021-02-25 20:30:01.138  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : -------------------
2021-02-25 20:30:01.238  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : TargetProductID=null; SourceProductID=30
2021-02-25 20:30:01.238  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : TargetProductID=10; SourceProductID=null
2021-02-25 20:30:01.238  INFO 84285 --- [           main] c.e.a.FooJpaApplication        : TargetProductID=20; SourceProductID=20
2021-02-25 20:30:01.243  INFO 84285 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
...
```

Comment: Well thats so perfectly working for my scenario @AlwaysLearning. Thanks a lot. But yah i will keep the question open since at procedure annotation does not work with this type in spring site. Well done and thanks again.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i missed the part where you map each of the interface methods, to the procedure output fields. Do you simply place the prefix 'get' before the field name ? I have some fields with underscores and I'm not sure if I should change that to camel case, for instance if the SP field is named L_TMP_SOME_FIELD, how should i declare it in my java interface ? I already tried String getLTmpSomeField(); getLtmpSomeField(); and getL_TMP_SOME_FIELD(); with no luck. could you help me please?